# Stuck while doing code first migration with Entity Framework Core 6.0

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, ef-code-first

I have created a project with .NET Core 6.0. I added class libraries. While doing migration of code, first approach in Entity Framework Core 6.0, I'm getting an error

> Unable to create an object of type 'AppDBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time'

This is the screenshot showing the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Package Source" drop-down to `nuget.org` and change the "Default Project" drop-down to the one that contains your application's `startup.cs` file